# How to set secret key in vercel environment variables?

Tags: json, environment-variables, vercel

I am trying to deploy my application, and added all the environment variables but of course, I got an error. Just what I needed. I only have a simple question and that is how do *you* guys set secret keys? Do you wrap it in single quotes or something? I only need an example to follow!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go to settings > Env variables , and put them here
You get 3 type of env , so you can add different key for each env.
Put keys without quote around and you will be fine

[image]